# Which ActiveDirectory objects can contain computers?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I need to browse [ActiveDirectory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) in order to select computer objects. As I find out, there are some containers that could have computer items, and the other can contain users, group policies, etc. I only want to show the containers which contains computers. So I use this code to check if container contains any computer:

```
public static bool CheckContainsComputers(DirectoryEntry entry)
{
    using (DirectorySearcher ds =
           new DirectorySearcher(entry, "(objectCategory=computer)", new string[0], SearchScope.Subtree))
    {
        ds.Asynchronous = true;
        ds.SizeLimit = 1;
        try
        {
            SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
            return (sr == null) ? false : true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. In order to reduce the count of call to this method I want to know - is it possible to find out if [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can contain computers without running the [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?
2. Is it possible with one call to [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [SearchScope.OneLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find containers, that can have computers, and computers

Answer (score 0):

1.If you already have your directoryEntry, there is no need to search for it again.
I think what you want is something like this :

```
if (entry.Properties["objectCategory"].Value.ToString().Contains("Computer"))
return true;
else
return false;
```

2.
Of course !

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myldapserver.com");
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
directorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
directorySearcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=computer)";
SearchResultCollection srCollection = directorySearcher.FindAll();
```

Comment: First assumption contains validation of the fact, that `entry` is a computer. The second one was described in the question. So, this is not an answer.